# How to seperate information from one row in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of positions + company names. Example: "senior manager at xxx company".

I need to separate the information that comes after the "at", so I can get only the company name. Which formula can I use to do that?

Many thanks in advance,
Ana

Comment: You nay use `=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("at ",A1)-1)` & fill down.

Answer (score 1):

```
B1 = left(A1,find(" at ",A1)-1)
C1 = mid(A1,find(" at ",A1)+3,len(A1))
```

Comment: This is mostly correct but should say +4 in the second formula, not +3

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data is in cell A1, you can enter the following formula in cell B1：

```
=MID(A1,FIND("at",A1)+2,99)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you are not a big fan of formulae enter the first company name manually in the adjacent column here cell B2 and drag as you would while filling a series but this time just click flash fill instead of the default fill series

Screenprint is available for your reference. This option works with Excel 2013 onwards.

[Flash Fill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UXPW.png)

Final Output after Flash Fill

[Final Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFeDg.png)

Comment: You mean to say Drag Separated Text,,, what if each cell has different company name after `at` ?

Comment: you need to type the first company name and then drag it then select Flashfill. It does not matter if you have a different company name as this works like a charm(please check the final output image). It also works if you dont have 'at' also.

Comment: ,, remember the Flash fill works in adjacent column only and the formula can be used any where, even on different sheet/workbook !!

Comment: Very true sir but still Flashfill is a good option to use and be familiar with

Comment: Yes it nice one but has limited scope,,, and a good answer has to consider every aspect ☺